# How to serialize a Marshmallow field under a different name

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, marshmallow

I want a Marshmallow `Schema`  with the following output json -

```
{
  "_id": "aae216334c3611e78a3e06148752fd79",
  "_time": 20.79606056213379,
  "more_data" : {...}
}
```

Marshmallow doesn't serialize private members so this is as close as I can get -

```
class ApiSchema(Schema):
    class Meta:
        strict = True

    time = fields.Number()
    id = fields.String()
```

But I do need the underscores in the output json.

Is there a way to tell Marshmallow to serialize the fields using different names?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The accepted answer (using `attribute`) didn't work for me, possibly [because](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#marshmallow.fields.Field):

> Note: This should only be used for very specific use cases such as outputting multiple fields for a single attribute. In most cases, you should use data_key instead.

However `data_key` worked nicely:

```
class ApiSchema(Schema):
    class Meta:
        strict = True

    _time = fields.Number(data_key="time")
    _id = fields.String(data_key="id")
```

Answer (score 26):

https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/2.x-line/quickstart.html#specifying-attribute-names

Even though the docs are for version 2, this seems to still work as of 3.5.1. The stable version 3 docs will not have this example.

```
class ApiSchema(Schema):
  class Meta:
      strict = True

  _time = fields.Number(attribute="time")
  _id = fields.String(attribute="id")
```

Comment: careful: https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/837
https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/upgrading.html?highlight=data_Key#load-from-and-dump-to-are-merged-into-data-key

Answer (score 11):

The answer's well documented in Marshmallows [api reference](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#module-marshmallow.fields).

I need to use `dump_to` :

```
class ApiSchema(Schema):
    class Meta:
        strict = True

    time = fields.Number(dump_to='_time')
    id = fields.String(dump_to='_id')
```

Comment: `dump_to` and `load_from` are replaced by `data_key` in Marshmallow 3.0.

Comment: If you liked this functionality and the ability to specify a difference between input and output schemas, then you must now create two schemas for input and output rather than specifying a simple kwarg. I can understand the design choice, as much as I don't like it. `data_key` does NOT fulfill the same role, as it modifies both the load and dump unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the [`dump`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#marshmallow.Schema.dump) method to *prepend* underscores to selected fields before returning the serialised object:

```
class ApiSchema(Schema):
    class Meta:
        strict = True

    time = fields.Number()
    id = fields.String()

    def dump(self, *args, **kwargs):
        special = kwargs.pop('special', None)
        _partial = super(ApiSchema, self).dump(*args, **kwargs)
        if special is not None and all(f in _partial for f in special):
            for field in special:
                _partial['_{}'.format(field)] = _partial.pop(field)
        return _partial
```

---

```
api_schema = ApiSchema(...)
result = api_schema.dump(obj, special=('id', 'time'))
```

You can also use the [`post_dump`](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#marshmallow.decorators.post_dump) decorator on a separate custom method without having to override `dump`, but then, you may have to hardcode the fields to-be-modified as part of the class, which may be inflexible depending on your use case.