# Custom field names in SQLAlchemy Meta Class Marshmellow

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I'm trying to use `.dump` for a query result using marshmallow from my sqlAlchemy query, but I would like to have the field's name custom (Not the same as the DB table column name) to send to the front-end.

So if my table schema is:

```
class SomeRandomName(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'some_random_name'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    time = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    title = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=False, nullable=True)
    some_column_name = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=False, nullable=True)
```

And my Marshmallow Schema is:

```
class SomeRandomNameSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ["time", "title", "some_column_name"]
```

The response will be:

```
[
    {"time": "2020-07-17 07:18:44",
    "title": "Some Title",
    "some_column_name": false}
]
```

but what I actually want is that my column name stays the same in DB but change the Key in the JSON response without manipulating the JSON after the `.dump`.

For Example:

```
[
    {"time": "2020-07-17 07:18:44",
    "title": "Some Title",
    "CulmnNameChanged": false}
]
```

I also tried suggested answers in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434180/how-to-serialize-a-marshmallow-field-under-a-different-name/58414104#58414104) but I end up with an empty JSON response.

the only way I could get the data was by putting `fields = ["time", "title", ...]` in my Class Meta

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58414104/5320906) in the linked duplicate candidate looks like the current way to do this see also https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/marshmallow.fields.html#marshmallow.fields.Field

Comment: I tried all of them but every time I end up with an empty JSON after the dump, the only way I could get the fields in JSON was with the fields=["field1", "field2"] in my Class Meta

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal reproduciable example? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the process of creating a reproducible example as requested in the comments, I ended up finding the answer which was by adding the `many=True` to the Marshmallow schema class since I was using `.all()` in my query and also using [the suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47040346/7881814) for my schema structure.

I will leave this here just as an example if anyone had the issue:

```
from app import db, ma
from marshmallow import fields


class Table(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'table'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=False, nullable=True)


class TableSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        strict = True
    newTitleName = fields.String(attribute="title")


def my_function():
    _query = db.session.query(Table).all()
    ser = TableSchema(many=True)
    result = ser.dump(_query)
    print(result)


my_function()
```