# Use "from" as a column name in sqlalchemy+marshmallow

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow-sqlalchemy

I have a table representing a phone call and want to store that data

```
from app.db import db
from app.schema import ma

#db = SQLAlchemy()
class phoneCall(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "phoneCalls"

    callerid = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    #from = db.Column(db.String)
    _from = db.Column("from", db.String)
    to = db.Column(db.String)
    duration = db.Column(db.Integer)

#ma = flask_marshmallow.Marshmallow()
class CallSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = phoneCall
```

Since `from` is a SQL keyword I can't directly use that as a column name. I tried setting it as

```
    _from = db.Column("from", db.String)
```

But when I return a `phoneCall.query.all()` I get the column name as `_from`. Additionally, I'm using a dict with the key as `from` to populate data into the table as well. How do get around this restricted keyword to accept input and also display the output of the query as

Input

```
call={'callid'='call34346346346',"duration":10 "from": "+1234", "to":"+1234"}
```

Expected output

```
[
    {
    "callerid": "call34346346346",
    "duration":10
    "from": "+1234",
    "to":"+1234"
    }
]
```

Actual output

```
[
    {
    "_from": "+1234",
    "callerid": "call34346346346",
    "duration":10
    "to":"+1234"
    }
]
```

Comment: If you want to change the column name in the database you will have to recreate the table or do a migration. For marshmallow, you need to use the `data_key` keyword as show in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58414104/5320906) in the linked duplicate.

Comment: I'm creating the database and the table, so there's no need for migration.

The data_key (and other suggestions in that answer) didn't work. I suspect it's because I'm using SQLAlchemyAutoSchema


 ```_from = fields.String(data_key="from")
TypeError: Raw.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data_key'```

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/hJxQN70j) worked for me (it uses vanilla SQLAlchemy, but that shouldn't make any difference).

Comment: Ah. Thanks for writing that up. I adopted that to `SQLAlchemyAutoSchema` and I think I was initially doing the indentation wrong. Once that was fixed the column name is showing up correctly. Thank you!